# Update nested react redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immer.js

I use react redux (with immer) to store the options and styles of my app after the initialization. How can I change the update function to update specific styles/options of the app, without changing the other options/styles ?

```
// reducer.js

export const common = produce((draft, action) => {
  if (!draft) {
    return {
      settings: {},
    };
  }
  switch (action.type) {
    case STORE_WIDGET_SETTINGS:
        draft.settings = action.payload.settings;
        return;

    case UPDATE_WIDGET_SETTINGS:
      draft.settings = action.payload.settings;
      return;

    default:
      return;
  }
});
```

The update function should only update the options/styles states without changing the current options/styles.

Example:
Settings before update:

```
    options: {
      selector: '#root'
    },
    styles: {
      mainContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        color: 'white',
      }
    }
```

Call update function with `option:{selector: '#container'}`.
The settings should be changed to:

```
options: {
  selector: '#container'
},
styles: {
  mainContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    color: 'white',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this manually you'll need to update each branch of your state on top of the existing values. You can do this by spreading the existing values and including the new values.

```js
draft.settings = {
  ...draft.settings, // Spread existing values
  ...action.payload.settings, // Override some values from action
  options: {
   ...draft.settings.options, // Spread existing values
   ...action.payload.settings.options // Override some values from action
  },
  styles: {
   ...draft.styles,
   ...action.payload.styles,
   mainContainer: {
   ...draft.styles.mainContainer,
   ...action.payload.mainContainer
   }
  }
}
```

Some things you can do to simplify this:

1) Flatten your state structure a bit so there's not so many nested objects. This will make updates easier and you can always re-build structures when you pull them out of the data (i.e. selectors). Something like Normalizr can help you with this: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

2) Break out a few more action types so that not every update happen in a single `UPDATE` action. Perhaps `UPDATE_MAIN_CONTAINER` etc.

3) Consider using something like Ramda's `merge` function to do this for you: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#merge

Links in this answer:

- Ramda merge - https://ramdajs.com/docs/#merge
- Normalizr - https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr